# Run-time error 13 occurs when deleting delete multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA in Excel. I've written the code below which works fine, but when I try to delete multiple cells a run-time error 13 occurs. I've checked other search problems but can't figure it out.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Peak Flow 120 and 180 Doctor Warning
If Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81")) = 180 Then
    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
End If
If Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81")) = 120 Then
    MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
End If
If Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81")) >= 450 Then
    MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is designed to handle only single cell changes...........to handle multiple cell changes, you would need a ***loop***.

Comment: You are a legend, your re-code worked perfectly. Thank you so much these Msgbox are so important. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rv As Long
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("C77:AD81"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
        rv = r.Value
        'Peak Flow 120 and 180 Doctor Warning
        If rv = 180 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 180L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''PREDNISONE PROBABLY REQUIRED''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS ASAP''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If
        If rv = 120 Then
            MsgBox "''PEAK FLOW CRITICAL AT 120L/MIN''" & vbCrLf & "''MAKE URGENT DOCTOR'S APPOINTMENTS''" & vbCrLf & "''OR GO TO A&E IMMEDIATELY''", vbInformation, "CRITICAL WARNING"
        End If
        If rv >= 450 Then
            MsgBox "''CHECK OR TEST PEAK FLOW METER''" & vbCrLf & "''IT MAY BE FAULTY AND GIVING FALSE HIGH's''", vbInformation, "WARNING"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```